# What is the location of Brave browser executable in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, brave

Earlier when I used Brave browser almost a year back, on a Windows 10 system the executable (brave.exe) was located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe
```

Now, after a year I've installed Brave browser on a different system but I'm unable to locate the Brave browser executable in the Windows 10 system.

This [discussion](https://community.brave.com/t/windows-cant-find-and-open-brave/88870) from the brave community mentions about:

```
C:\Users\Users\username\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\
```

But I'm unable to find it there even.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Launch Brave, open Task Manager, find the Brave process, (expand it if necessary), right-click, select Open file location.

Comment: If you have a working short-cut, just do a right-click > "Open File Location". If you do it via the Windows Start menu, you have to go to more and then Open file location, followed by another right-click > "Open File Location".

Answer (score 0):

I checked it on my system and the application is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe
```

or

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).